# BigQuery/I can't correctly result using "in" clauses

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to extract perfectly match data, not partical match data.
But, I can't extract them, if I execute sql code of the below:

I estimate this sql code extract no data , but this extract all rows of data.

【SQL code】

```
WITH a AS(
    SELECT
        001 AS id_a,
        112345678901234567 AS x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        002,
        112345678901233567
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        003,
        112345678901232568
),
comp_a AS(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        a
    WHERE
        x IN(112345678901234000, 112345678901233000, 112345678901232000)
),
comp_b AS(
    SELECT
        004 AS id_b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        005
)
SELECT
    id_a,
    id_b
FROM
    comp_a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        comp_b
    ON  (
            comp_a.id_a = comp_b.id_b
        )
WHERE
    comp_b.id_b IS NULL
;
```

I think  "in" clauses are used for perfectly match.
But, perhaps, I think this sql code isn't executed  "in" clauses , but  it is executed "like" clauses.

I will be glad you answer solution of my question.

■Further note:
　・I deleted cashe of browser and Bigquery. But I couldn't solve it.
　・This sql code is sample code , because I can't expose real sql code.
  ・I can recreate this problem in One enviroment of BigQuery,
    but I can't recreate in Other enviroment of BigQuery.
    This Problem may be not problem of sql code , but problem of enviroment
    or setting.

Comment: You might want to post the actual `IN` clause, as your pseudo code is not clear (at least not to me).

Comment: 'deleted cashe of browser and Bigquery didn't help' - have you tried power off your PC?

Comment: Ok. obviously that was a joke :o) instead of doing not relevant things  - rather read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and follow recommendations so we actually will be able to help you. Help us to help you!!!

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I wrote sql code you can execute.

Comment: i am still not sure  - what is expected output? you might want to read again the link I provided above

Comment: To Mikhail Berlyant , Thank you for trying.  Yes , I expected that result you got.  But ,  I can't  recreate this in my PC "A"  but I can recreate this in my PC "B".  I predict  to make difference between BigQuery setting of PC "A" and BigQuery setting PC "B".     However , I can't find some points  I solve this problem.

Comment: To Mikhail Berlyant ,  about "what is expected output?"  , I expect this sql code extract no data. But  this sql code extract 3 rows data(all rows).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answering my question.

I solved my question.
The cause of my problem is not BigQuery , but it is the format of Excel.

Detail:
I tried to check data using Excel , Because the results are a lot of data.
Sad to say , Because of the format of Excel is numeric type , a part of number data are rounded. So I misunderstood the correct result to the wrong result.

Sorry about my misunderstanding.